# Can I enter a Win7 license to "upgrade" my Win10 preview to release?

Tags: windows-10-preview, windows-10-upgrade

I have Windows 10 installed on a laptop with a Windows 7 license, but I did not do a upgrade from Win7 to Win10. Can I somehow skip that and just enter my license key somewhere?

Comment: I previously stated that Windows 10 Insider Preview users were not eligible for the free upgrade to Windows 10. I was mistaken based on some new information I discovered.  The catch is, to get a legitimate installation which won't expire after a few months, you have had to upgrade the insider Preview over a eligible Windows installation.  If that describers you then you have to do nothing, when the RTM build is released, you will be given the option to install it. If you did not do this, then you are out of luck, so rollback your installation to Windows 7 if you want the free license

Answer (score 1):

This will not work. The only way around this is to reinstall Windows 7 and then perform the free upgrade from there.

Remember that Windows 10 preview is still considered beta software and wasn't intended to be a comprehensive upgrade to 10.

And of course, make sure you backup everything prior to installing 7.

Comment: Technically, Microsoft did intend for Insider Preview users to continue to use it, just not as their actual operating system but as testers hence the ability to continue to use and receive updates to the Insider Preview after July 29th.

Comment: Which is why it's not comprehensive.